# How can I protect login popup with https

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, authentication

we are developing a website with multiple "call to action" links which display "Register / Login" popup if user is not logged in. That popup is displayed by means on jquery UI popup. We want to protect login/registration pages with HTTPS. It's clear how to do this when these are standalone pages. But what will be the solution for a "normal" page which MIGHT have login popup displayed?

Obviously, if we force the whole website to work through HTTPS then this will be solved. But are there other ways?

Not sure if it matters, but we are using C# MVC3 with jQuery 1.7

Thank you.

Comment: Well this is a confusing issue to the end user really more than anything. If I am logging in to a website I expect to see a lock for a secure site in my browser. So to make everyone happy just make everything HTTPS

Comment: The other way, yes you can serve up your "popup" via HTTPS but will the end user know, or care?

Comment: hmm - how would I serve my popup via HTTPS? I need it more for compliance and peace of mind rather than for the "lock" in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, posting from an http url to an https url is problematic.  Older versions of IE will completely block this.  You could load an https iframe in the jQuery pop-up, but that's getting messy.  Additionally, users won't have the spiffy green lock in their address bar if only the iframe is https.  The cleanest way to do it is push the entire site into https or at least the pages that include the "Register / Login" popup.

Comment: Which versions of IE will block this? and what will the user see? how do they block it and what do they report as the reason for blocking?

Comment: I don't recall if IE 7 and 8 do it, but IE 6 has a pop up with "are you sure you want to see insecure content" which is such a horrible user experience it may as well be a block.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not concerned about an SSL notifier in the address bar, I'd say the only solution I can think of which satisfies your requirements would be to serve the login form via an iframe loaded into the jQuery popup.

This would prevent you from having to enable HTTPS on every page that may not use it, and by creating the iframe dynamically with jQuery, the secure connection will really only be used when necessary.